# Unity. Значения 'y' при разном разрешении экрана

Tags: unity3d, экран, touch

У меня есть слайдер и панель.
При таче на панели и перетаскивании пальца вверх/вниз - берутся координаты, и меняется значение переменной, от которой зависит value слайдера

Но проблема в том, что при разном разрешении экрана, меняется и диапазон значений 'y'.

Если разрешение 800х480 то максимальное 'y' == 480
Если разрешение 2960х1440 то максимальное 'y' == 1440

Как сделать чтобы диапазон значений currentPosition не зависил от разрешения экрана?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class FuckingScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    Slider slider;
    public float volume = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        slider = GameObject.Find("VolumeBar").GetComponent<Slider>();
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Vector2 currentPosition = eventData.position;
        volume = currentPosition.y*2/1000; 
        slider.value = volume;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData){}
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData){}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Что бы диапазон значений currentPosition не зависил от разрешения экрана, не нужно ориентироваться на значение разрешения! Например считать в процентах от высоты экрана.